# How to escape hash symbol in a string in php

Tags: php, hash, escaping, symbols

How do you escape the hash symbol in PHP?

I want to do `"DELETE FROM [#8:1]"` but to make it work I have to do `"DELETE FROM [".'#'."8:1]"`. Whilst it works, it looks a little bit clumsy, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "DELETE FROM [#8:1]" should work as is...

Comment: can you just use single quotes your solution to be fair looks ok

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes

```
'DELETE FROM [#8:1]'
```